# global name 'show' is not defined when plotting in ipython notebook

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I tried to do a plot in the ipython notebook by calling a function that does the plot, but get an error. This is the code in the notebook:

```
from mynamd.logutils import plot_energy_column
plot_energy_column('3x3x3/eq0.log', 4) # print dihedral
```

This is plot_energy_column:

```
def plot_energy_column(logfile,column):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.xlabel('time'); plt.ylabel(energy_keys[column])
    plt.plot( fetch_energy_column(logfile,1), fetch_energy_column(logfile,column) )
    plt.show()
```

Here's the error:

---

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-97-8ef7f9adebf3> in <module>()
      1 from mynamd.logutils import plot_energy_column,fetch_energy_column
----> 2 plot_energy_column('3x3x3/eq0.log', 4) # print dihedral
      3 #show()

/home/jbq/code/python/mynamd/logutils.py in plot_energy_column(logfile, column)
     28     plt.xlabel('time'); plt.ylabel(energy_keys[column])
     29     plt.plot( fetch_energy_column(logfile,1), fetch_energy_column(logfile,column))
---> 30     plt.show()
     31 
     32 

NameError: global name 'show' is not defined
```

I get the seme error if I remove `plt.show()` from the `plot_energy_function` definition and stick a `show()` at the end of the ipython notebook. Any clarifications are T-appreciated.

Jose

Comment: did you start ipython with `--pylab` ?

Comment: Yes, I did: `ipython notebook --pylab inline --notebook-dir=\`pwd\``

Comment: are you shadowing `plt` someplace?  You have farkled your name spaces and there is no way to sort out where from what you have shown.

Comment: I replaced `plt` with `matplotlib.pyplot` within `plot_energy_column`. Now the import line is just `import matplotlib`. Unfortunately, I still get the same error. However, I created a notebook containing only the two lines I report. Then I have no error when executing. There must be something else in the original notebook giving rise to the error, but it's too big to put it here :(

Comment: it is also odd that it only shows up on `show`... are you sure you are using an interactive backend?

Comment: Sounds like some diagnostics are in order. Can you run `print dir(plt)` and `print plt.__file__` right before plt.show() so that you can see if it's importing the right package? Also what do you get with `matplotlib.__version__`?

Comment: Have you changed the code since you imported the function? Try restarting the kernel (Kernel menu in the notebook) and re-running it. The error you show can't come from the line of code the traceback is pointing to.